# how to implement a phonebook-like application

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have a problem which requires data to be stored in memory for users. The structure contains user_name and phone_number and I have to store it for say 1 million users. Now while retrieving if user_name is given as input then it should return the phone_number and if phone_number is given as input then it should return the user_name. What will be the appropriate data structure to implement this when I need optimized complexity while retrieving in terms of speed and storage.

Comment: Try a database. They do work.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I have to store it in memory.

Comment: I would be tempted to use two `std::map`s containing pointers to a `struct` type object containing the actual data. You would need to write your own comparators to sort each map's key according to either the pointed to username or the pointed to phone number. And I'd probably wrap that all up in its own class.

Comment: @paper.plane [`rc = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);`](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)

Comment: @paper.plane this smells like homework to be honest, but anyway, using a simple index for phone nr lookup might not be what you're aiming for, no matter whether it's handish implemented or some DB; you might like to take a look at [Struggling with a MySQL database of phone numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321802/struggling-with-a-mysql-database-of-phone-numbers)

Comment: Use a binary tree? I don't know but it seems like it'd be efficient for searches. Not sure how it'd work for duplicate names though. I guess a plain old `std::map<char, std::vector<Phone>>` would work.. you'd search for 'a', 'b', 'c', etc.. and it'd return a list of users that have the key as their last name's initial. Iterate the list and narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

try `boost::bimap`.
It's a bidirectional map (everything is a key and also a value).

[Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)

I think it's implemented with two maps though so note the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Try leveldb, where you can store data in the form of key & value pairs.