# regex for simple mobile number(Scala Style)

Tags: java, regex, string, scala

simply i want a regex in **scala style** for mobile number.

ex:-

+9198989898989

+11234545745892

the total digits including `+` can be from **6 to 18**(i think all valid number lies in between of it)

if number match regex returns `true` else `false`.

```
type S = String
  def parseMobile(number:S):Boolean={
  val phoneRx = """[+\d() ]{6,18}"""          // absolutely wrong regex
  number.matches(phoneRx)
  }
```

Comment: `\+\d{6,18}` should do it I think

Comment: 17 digits long mobile number?

Comment: We need to make sure how long will the country code  be ......coz after that mobile no will begin which should not begin with 0.So is there a max length or something for country code?

Comment: @vks i am getting number in this format and can't distinguish the country code

Comment: There must be some max length for the country code......without it regex for this question will never be correct..........see for ex : +910987654321 this is an invalid number but regex will never be able to tell this.untill we define a max length for country code

Comment: @vks its my bad Luck, but i have a second validation also from twilio Api also, so i didn't worry about it.(just i am here to reduce some traffic)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543938/how-to-split-mobile-number-into-country-code-area-code-and-local-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like so should work: `^\+?\d{6,18}$`. This regex assumes that the plus might not be there. More information on the regex can be found [here](http://regex101.com/r/mH7kM0/2).

If you want to exclusively match the `+`, then this will work: `^\+\d{5,17}$`

Comment: 6 to 18 including `+`. change the regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've asked for a regex, but if you'd like something that's easier to read and maintain (and is probably a little faster), how about using pure Scala:

```
def isPhoneNumber(str: String): Boolean =
  str.startsWith("+") && 6 <= str.size && str.size <= 18 && 
    str.drop(1).forall(_.isDigit)
```